# Compute the area of specific shapes

Tags: geometry, area

I'm trying to calculate the dashed area in the following pictures, and I can't solve them. I tried to guess the areas, subtract some shapes from others, but I'm confused if I calculated them wrong or correct.

Problem 1 https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldS9T.jpg
Problem 2 https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GAgM.jpg

Comment: What is $\gamma $ supposed to represent exactly?

Comment: it's not part of question, it is the material index of that area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said in my comment, what we would like to do is use the equality

*Area of Big Triangle = Area of Little Triangle + Area of Trapezium*

*Area of Big Triangle* = $\frac {\sqrt 3} 4 a^2$

*Area of Little Triangle* = $\frac {\sqrt 3} 4 (a-\alpha).b $

*Area of Trapezium*= $\frac 1 2 (a+b)\frac {\sqrt 3} 2 \alpha$

Where b is the side we want to find. 
After simplification we get
$$a^2=(a-\alpha).b+(a+b)\alpha$$
$$a^2=(ab+\alpha a)$$
$$b=a-\alpha$$

If you input this into the *Area of Trapezium* you get an area of $\frac {\sqrt 3} 2 \alpha (a-\frac \alpha 2) $

Now as I mentioned in my previous comment, the second one should be easy as it is identical to the first. Use the fact that it is equilateral, and use trigonometry to find the height of the trapezium.

Answer (score 0):

Triangles in both problems are equilateral which simplifies solutions. My results are:

The area in problem 1 is
\begin{equation}
\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \alpha (a - \frac{\alpha}{2}).
\end{equation}

The area in problem 2 is
\begin{equation}
\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4} a^2 (2\alpha - \alpha^2).
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

If you increase $\alpha$ (from $0$ to $1$), the width of the hatched area goes decreasing linearly, like $1-\alpha$.

Hence, the fraction of the triangle area that is hatched is proportional to the integral

$$\int_0^\alpha(1-\alpha)\,d\alpha=\alpha-\frac{\alpha^2}2.$$

As the integral up to $1$ equals $\dfrac12$ the relative fraction of the area is given by
$$2\alpha-\alpha^2.$$

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1. Let $x$ be the base of the small triangle & the side of trapezium then using simple geometry, we have $$x=a-a\left(\frac{\frac{\alpha\sqrt{3}}{2}}{\frac{a\sqrt{3}}{2}}\right)\implies \color{blue}{x=a-\alpha}$$ Now we have $$\text{area of trapezuim}=\frac{1}{2}(\text{sum of lengths of parallel sides})\left(\text{normal distance between parallel sides }\right)$$$$=\frac{1}{2}(a+x)\left(\frac{\alpha\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)$$  $$=\frac{1}{2}(a+a-\alpha)\left(\frac{\alpha\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)$$$$\color{blue}{=\frac{\alpha\sqrt{3}}{2}\left(a-\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)}$$

Problem 2. 
Let $x$ be the base of the small triangle & the side of trapezium then using simple geometry, we have $$x=a-a\left(\frac{\frac{\alpha a}{2}}{\frac{a\sqrt{3}}{2}}\right)\implies \color{blue}{x=a-\frac{\alpha a}{\sqrt{3}}}$$ Now we have $$\text{area of trapezuim}=\frac{1}{2}(\text{sum of lengths of parallel sides})\left(\text{normal distance between parallel sides }\right)$$$$=\frac{1}{2}(a+x)\left(\frac{\alpha a}{2}\right)$$$$=\frac{1}{2}\left(a+a-\frac{\alpha a}{\sqrt{3}}\right)\left(\frac{\alpha a}{2}\right)$$  $$\color{blue}{=\frac{\alpha a^2}{4}\left(2-\frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{3}}\right)}$$